# Solving a tensor equation in xTensor

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve the following equation

$\frac{1}{4} R_{ab} g_{cd} - \frac{1}{2} g_{ab} R_{cd} + 4 R_{ab} g^{ef} \nabla_e \nabla_f R_{cd} 
+ 2 g_{ab} R_{cd} g^{ih} g^{ef} \nabla_e \nabla_f R_{ih} =  g^{ef} \nabla_a R_{cd} \nabla_b R_{ef}$

using xTensor. I use the following code

```
SolveAlways[
1/4 RicciCD[-a, -b] g[-c, -d] - 1/2 g[-a, -b] RicciCD[-c, -d] + 
4 RicciCD[-a, -b] g[e, f] CD[-e]@CD[-f]@RicciCD[-c, -d]
+ 2 g[-a, -b] RicciCD[-c, -d] g[e, f] g[i, h] CD[-i]@
CD[-h]@RicciCD[-e, -f]
== g[e, f] (CD[-a]@RicciCD[-c, -d]) CD[-b]@RicciCD[-e, -f], 
RicciCD[-a, -b]]
```

but I get the output

```
InverseFunction::ifun: Inverse functions are being used. Values may be 
lost for multivalued inverses. >>

General::stop: Further output of InverseFunction::ifun will be 
suppressed during this calculation. >>
```

Any ideas?

If I use Solve instead of SolveAlways then I get a formula for $R_{ab}$ in terms of $R_{cd}$, i.e. it does not recognise that they are the same tensor

Comment: In _Mathematica_ `=` is not the same as `==`.

Comment: Thanks! It's working now, but unfortunately it has solved the equation by assuming g_{ab} and g_{cd} are unrelated and that a covariant derivative is simply a tensor that can be set to zero, rather than an operator

Comment: @supercoolphysicist OK now that you have the simple syntax error out of the way, and since y our question has not received answers yet, I would suggest that you edit your question to reflect the problem you described in the comment above. Otherwise the question as it stands is likely to be closed as trivial.